# Access a Kubernetes Service running locally in Docker For Desktop?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using Docker For Desktop with the built-in Kubernetes cluster. I have installed a `Pod` that serves resources over HTTP, but I'm not sure how to access it using my browser. I have the following `ServiceSpec` that correctly routes traffic to the `Pod`:

```
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.99.132.220
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: myport
    nodePort: 31534
    port: 8037
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And I can see it set up when I query it with `kubectl`:

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
myservice   LoadBalancer   10.99.132.220   localhost     8037:31534/TCP   1h
```

How do I reach this service using my browser?

Comment: Btw, if you're on Docker Desktop for Windows, this is a great guide for making `docker` and `kubectl` on your host computer available within the Ubuntu system. (for if there are Linux shell scripts a guide tells you to run, or what-not): https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That service will be available in your browser at http://localhost:8037

Note that the port `8037` corresponds to the `port` property on the `ServiceSpec` object.

If you are unable to reach the service at that URL, then it could be one of several things, including but not limited to:

- There is another `Service` in your cluster that has claimed that port. Either delete the other `Service`, or change the `port` property to an unclaimed port.
- Your `Pod` is not running and ready. Check `kubectl get pods`.

Comment: Works for a `NodePort` also :)

Comment: port is the port exposed on the docker image, nodePort is the port that kubernetes binds on to the local-machine, or what would be the port on the worker node if this were a "proper" cluster.

Comment: @PapaMufflon , I tried on `NodePort` but didn't work for me in docker desktop k8s cluster. @Gudlaugur Egilsson , since port is the service port, I am bit confused about how we can access through localhost.

Answer (score 16):

##### Port forwarding:

```
kubectl port-forward <my-pod-name> 4000:8037
```

Your pod's internal port (8037) will be accessible on `localhost:4000`.
Docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

Comment: This worked for me, follwwing along in the Kubernetes Book  '23 edition. even though he recommends to use localhost and the nodePort. This was unable to connect to ther node, I needed to use port forwarding

Answer (score 12):

For local development you might want to use the type `NodePort` for the service (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). This binds the given `nodePort`, as the name says, to a port of your node (which should be localhost for docker-on-desktop).

Then the the service should be available ob http://localhost:31534.

Comment: One can patch a service with: `kubectl patch svc/<service> -p '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'` to make it available on the `localhost`.

Answer (score -3):

First of all 2 are different way 1. MiniKube and 2. Docker-desktop.

For Docker-Desktop on Mac , you can always use localhost but more good approach below.

1. Go to any pod and access with your cluster node IP.
2. Run busybox and go to cluster node IP to access application.

How to get IP of your cluster.

```
$ kubectl describe node docker-for-desktop
```

Search below

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.65.3
  Hostname:    docker-desktop
```

With above IP you can run the command , in busybox. Please note that , you can not directly access above IP but you need to login first any pod of cluster of that namespace.