# Expose your app publicly doesn't work on local kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running local kubernetes cluster installed as a part of Docker Desktop.

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:18:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I am creating deployment by running

```
kubectl create deployment firstkube-deployment --image=firstkube:v1
deployment.apps/firstkube-deployment created
```

Then exposing the deployment by

```
kubectl expose deployment firstkube-deployment --type=NodePort --port=8080
service/firstkube-deployment exposed
```

The kubectl describe services command returns the following

```
kubectl describe services/firstkube-deployment
Name:                     firstkube-deployment
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=firstkube-deployment
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=firstkube-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.107.205.123
LoadBalancer Ingress:     localhost
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31448/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.8:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

The request to http://127.0.0.1:31448/ from browser fails with
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

If I am trying to reach my app using api proxy, by requesting
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/firstkube-deployment-6778f8d74-qhgz2/proxy/
I am able to get response back, the application is app and running.

I have tried the proposed solution from this post
[Access a Kubernetes Service running locally in Docker For Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178696/access-a-kubernetes-service-running-locally-in-docker-for-desktop)
It doesn't help.

Providing also pods info

```
kubectl describe pods
Name:         firstkube-deployment-6778f8d74-qhgz2
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:   Sat, 27 Jun 2020 18:30:38 -0400
Labels:       app=firstkube-deployment
              pod-template-hash=6778f8d74
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/firstkube-deployment-6778f8d74
Containers:
  firstkube:
    Container ID:   docker://1662d883b9f049a5e4fa0eab9283e2eefdfac80b0ce95ac6db02c89d9357cf18
    Image:          firstkube:v2
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:78332407ac919779bc6fb331b955bcdd0183452a8e699c8552c6cbca05978c42
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 27 Jun 2020 18:30:39 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-8tfz2 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-8tfz2:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-8tfz2
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  Scheduled  10m   default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/firstkube-deployment-6778f8d74-qhgz2 to docker-desktop
  Normal  Pulled     10m   kubelet, docker-desktop  Container image "firstkube:v2" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    10m   kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container firstkube
  Normal  Started    10m   kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container firstkube
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a Kubernetes Service running locally in Docker For Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178696/access-a-kubernetes-service-running-locally-in-docker-for-desktop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, see my comments inline.

Comment: Have you specified the service as loadbalancer as described in the question or you were using nodePort for testing that solution?

Comment: See the output of kubectl describe services

Comment: "It doesn't help" is not an information that helps with debugging your case. There are things that you can check to verify where the problem lies. First schedule another pod and from inside of it curl the service that you created and curl the localhost and let us know the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with kubectl expose deployment command. It needs to be provided port 80

```
kubectl expose deployment firstkube-deployment --type=NodePort --port=80
service/firstkube-deployment exposed
```

Then get services returns the following

```
kubectl get services/firstkube-deployment
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
firstkube-deployment   NodePort   10.96.23.130   <none>        80:32001/TCP   32s
```

Now I can reach my application in browser by requesting http://localhost:32001

Answer (score 2):

Few pointers to debug the issue

1. The service has got `10.1.0.7:8080` in the `Endpoints` but the pod IP is `10.1.0.4`. Check if there is another pod with same label `app=firstkube-deployment`
2. Check if you are able to access the pod directly by it's IP and port from another pod in the cluster. If that does  not work then check if the application inside the pod is listening in `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Also check if the pod is listening on `8080` or some other port.

Comment: Regarding your first point -  sorry for the confusion, I just updated the output of kubectl describe services, the service endpoint and pod IP are the same. It was my bad, I reseted the cluster therefor the ips were different. As you can see from describe pods command, there's only one pod so no othere pod here. Regarding the second one - could you please eleborate how I can do those checks.

Comment: exec into the pod and use netstat to check . If netstat is not installed then install it