# NodePort Error Connection Refused (Docker Desktop, Windows, Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Everytime I try to access a NodePort on my machine, it says "Error Connection Refused." I don't understand since the examples I read online imply that I can run Docker Desktop on my laptop, connect to the cluster, and access services via their nodeport.

My machine:

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop (tested additionally with `k3s` and `minikube` with similar results)
- Kubernetes 1.19+

Kubernetes Configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ngnix-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30007
```

Output and cURL test:

```
PS C:\Users\ME\nginx> kubectl get svc
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          169m
ngnix-service   NodePort    10.108.214.243   <none>        80:30007/TCP     7m19s

PS C:\Users\ME\nginx> curl.exe http://localhost:30007
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 30007: Connection refused
```

I've also tried with the node ip:

```
PS C:\Users\ME\nginx> kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
docker-desktop   Ready    master   6d    v1.19.7   192.168.65.4   <none>        Docker Desktop   5.10.25-linuxkit   docker://20.10.5

PS C:\Users\ME\nginx> curl.exe http://192.168.65.4:30007
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.65.4 port 30007: Timed out
```

I get the same response when trying to access a NodePort from my browser (Chrome). `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Is there something I'm missing? Why are all NodePorts inaccessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes run locally, still runs on its internal network.

> curl.exe http://192.168.65.4:30007

Here you use an IP address that is internal Kubernetes network. You must expose your Kubernetes service so that it gets an cluster-external address.

See this part:

```
EXTERNAL-IP
<none>
```

You typically expose the service outside the cluster with a Service of `type: Loadbalancer` or use an Ingress-gateway.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50178697/213269) on how you can change your Service from `type:NodePort` to `type: LoadBalancer` to expose it to your localhost.

The easiest way to access your service is to use `kubectl port-forward`, e.g.

```
kubectl port-forward ngnix-service 8080:80
```

Then you can access it on `localhost:8080`.

See [Use Port Forwarding to Access Applications in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: Thanks that clears it up for me. My main problem is port-forwarding is not an option (though I have used it to confirm my service is working). I can't use `LoadBalancer` since my machine doesn't have a local `LoadBalancer`. Docker Desktop just leaves my `external-ip` as `<pending>`. I'll just have to find another way around this I suppose. Maybe MetalLb.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful for anyone. I was facing similar issues where NodePort was properly created with entrypoint pointing to the correct containerPort and IP. Yet, I wasn't able to curl the NodePort. After a day of searching, here is what unblocked me. And thought I would share to save people the pain of searching.

After running (for mac)

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/pki/
```

For windows, the folder is C:/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/pki

Then restart docker desktop

Source (https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3594#issuecomment-621487150)